# Redirect to login with attribute Authorize using cookies authentication in ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am testing the *[Authorize]* attribute, but I can't make a redirect to login page if the user has not logged yet (the Chrome inspector returns a 401).

This is my code to make the login in my **Controller** (very simple).

```
if (model.UserName == "admin" && model.Password == "test")
{
    var claims = new[] { new Claim("name", model.UserName), new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin") };
    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

And this is my configuration in the **Startup.cs** for logins:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
    });
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you provide us your `Startup.cs` as well as the controller you are trying to secure? It seems to me that it might be one of your `app.Use..()` that might in the wrong order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Startup.cs should look like the following:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    LoginPath = "/account/login",

    AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true
});
```

Setting the AutomaticChallenge is what is going to make the [Authorize] attribute work. Be sure to include the [Authorize] attribute on any of the controllers you want the redirect (302) to happen.

There is a very basic sample in this GitHub repo that might provide some guidance:
https://github.com/leastprivilege/AspNet5TemplateCookieAuthentication

Comment: Actually the scheme property doesn't "make authorize work". It's there to enable filtering, and also to enable you to manually auth. It's simply a label. AutomaticChallenge is what causes the redirect pieces to work.

Comment: @blowdart Agreed, what I meant was, and it might not be needed because of default values, is that the authorization scheme/policy enforced by default by the [Authorize] is "Cookies" so redirect wouldn't work for a Custom scheme with a diff name.  I just removed that part as for this scenario it is not relevant.  Thanks!

Comment: Authorize will go through all registered Authentication middleware whose AutomaticAuthenticate property is true/ There is no default. Cookie middleware does set that property to true by default though.

Comment: Thanks, @blowdart .. Got to be honest would love to take this off StackOverflow and discuss further.   As most folks, my knowledge comes from discovery and docs.  But for example looking at, https://github.com/mrsheepuk/ASPNETSelfCreatedTokenAuthExample/blob/master/src/TokenAuthExampleWebApplication/Startup.cs  .. I get confused as I see we had to define a custom Authorization policy for [Authorize] to work in our project for Bearer tokens.  I know this is not a Forum so, if you want to take this convo to another place, I would love to keep drilling you for more info.  Again, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the **Startup.cs**:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(options =>
{
   options.AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
   options.AutomaticAuthenticate = true;
   options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
   options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
});
```

And this in the **Controller**

```
IAuthenticationManager authManager = Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
authManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
```

Comment: You're missing AutomaticChallenge = true